# Get rid of terminal style borders like `+-----------` around csv output from odbc connection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, odbc, unixodbc

I have an odbc connection to Google Big Query using unixODBC.E.g:

```
root@e0824e3bec23:/# isql -v BigQuery
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL> select 1 as blah;
+---------------------+
| blah                |
+---------------------+
| 1                   |
+---------------------+
SQLRowCount returns -1
1 rows fetched
```

My connection works. This is in the terminal and I can see all these dashes `'---'` around the data. But, if I try to export this, those dashes remain:

```
root@e0824e3bec23:/# echo "select 1 as bla;" > query.sql
root@e0824e3bec23:/# isql -v -b BigQuery < query.sql > results.csv
root@e0824e3bec23:/# cat results.csv 
+---------------------+
| bla                 |
+---------------------+
| 1                   |
+---------------------+
SQLRowCount returns -1
1 rows fetched
```

When I download the csv file with some real data and open on a desktop application, (libreoffice), those dashes are still there:
[image]

I'm not sure if I should look in unixodbc flags or settings or in the simba odbc settings. I've researched both and not found a solution. IN case it's relevant, my odbc connection contains these name value pairs:

```
[BigQuery]
KeyFilePath=/service.json
Driver=/opt/simba/driver/lib/libgooglebigqueryodbc_sb64.so
OAuthMechanism=0
Catalog=somecatalog
AllowLargeResults=0
LargeResultsDataSetId=_bqodbc_temp_tables
LargeResultsTempTableExpirationTime=3600000
```

How can I export just the data without all those dashes and borders?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the 'd' flag to specify comma delimited (and -c to keep header):

```
isql -v -b -c -d, BigQuery < query.sql > results.csv

root@058433ed62ca:/# isql -h

**********************************************
* unixODBC - isql                            *
**********************************************
* Syntax                                     *
*                                            *
*      isql DSN [UID [PWD]] [options]        *
*                                            *
* Options                                    *
*                                            *
* -b         batch.(no prompting etc)        *
* -dx        delimit columns with x          *
* -x0xXX     delimit columns with XX, where  *
*            x is in hex, ie 0x09 is tab     *
* -w         wrap results in an HTML table   *
* -c         column names on first row.      *
*            (only used when -d)             *
* -mn        limit column display width to n *
* -v         verbose.                        *
* -lx        set locale to x                 *
* -q         wrap char fields in dquotes     *
* -3         Use ODBC 3 calls                *
* -n         Use new line processing         *
* -e         Use SQLExecDirect not Prepare   *
* -k         Use SQLDriverConnect            *
* -L         Length of col display (def:300) *
* --version  version                         *
*                                            *
* Commands                                   *
*                                            *
* help - list tables                         *
* help table - list columns in table         *
* help help - list all help options          *
*                                            *
* Examples                                   *
*                                            *
*      isql WebDB MyID MyPWD -w < My.sql     *
*                                            *
*      Each line in My.sql must contain      *
*      exactly 1 SQL command except for the  *
*      last line which must be blank (unless *
*      -n option specified).                 *
*                                            *
* Please visit;                              *
*                                            *
*      http://www.unixodbc.org               *
*      nick@lurcher.org                      *
*      pharvey@codebydesign.com              *
**********************************************
```